# How I can access a hidden variable in C

Tags: c, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access a shadowed global variable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c)

In C++, I can use `::` operator to specify a global variable. For example:

```
using namespace std;
int foo = 10;
int main(){
     int foo = 5;
     cout<<" Global variable: "<< ::foo <<endl;
     cout<<" Local Variable: " << foo <<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

How can I do this in C?

Answer (score 8):

This was subject of [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c). It can be achieved as follows

```
int foo = 10;
int main(void) {
     int foo = 5;
     {
         extern int foo;
         foo++;
     }
     foo++
     return 0;
}
```

However in practice, I can't imagine running into this problem, because I could always rename the local variable or create a small `static inline` function that can access the global `foo` and that I could call.