# Accessing global variable hidden by local

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables, shadowing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I access a shadowed global variable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c)

How to access global variable in C , if there is local variable with same name?

```
int m = 20;
int main(void)
{
    int m = 30;
}
```

Comment: C or C++? The answer is different... Also, if you write a wrong title you can edit it...

Comment: Since the body only mentions C, I've removed the C++ tag, especially since the answers will be different: "no" and "::" (from memory, so I could be wrong).

Answer (score 6):

In C, you can. Of course this is just trivia, you should never do so in real life.

Declaring something `extern` can be done anywhere, and always links the declared variable to the global of that name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 3;

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    int i = 6;

    printf( "%d\n", i );
    { // need to introduce a new scope
        extern int i; // shadowing is allowed here.

        printf( "%d\n", i );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In C++, the global is always available as `::i`.

Comment: Woa, this is an interesting trick, +1!

Comment: @Potatoswatter, sorry for the noise

Answer (score 4):

<s>In C there's no way.</s> actually, introducing an extra scope and with an `extern` declaration you can, see @Potatoswatter's answer.

In C++ you can look up identifiers in the global namespace using `::` (as in `::m=15`), which, by the way, is the same operator used to access members of "regular" namespaces (`std::cout`, ...).

Also, it's `int main()`.

Answer (score 2):

In C you don't. Give them a different name, it's confusing and a bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Same name is bad practice anyway until `m` is redefined you are accessing the global variable anyway

```
int m = 20;
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", m); // 20 would be printed here
    // Max you can do
    int m = 30;
}
```