# Global variable validation?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am expecting the output to be 10
But i get 11
as per my knowledge while calling fun function, it should take the
global variable. ??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace first;
int var = 0;

void fun()
{
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{  
    var = 1;
    cout << var;
    fun();
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `10`?

Comment: Yes, it uses the global variable, which you modified.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth because fun() would take the value of global var =0 ?

Comment: But you have set the value of the global variable `var` to `1` just before calling `fun()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reassigning the value of 'var' to 1 and then printing 'var' two times. that's why you get 11 as output.

Comment: how can the var inside main( ) update the global var ??

Comment: @user3127386 the `var` inside `main()` *is* the global variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza so you mean we can update global variables from any type of local scope ?

Comment: @user3127386: yes, that's what's meant by "global" ;)

Comment: @juanchopanza can we update local variables from a global scope, anyhow? no i am guessing.???

Comment: @user3127386 no, the reverse isn't true, that's why local variables aren't global. Look up "variable scope" on Google.

Answer (score 4):

You only declare `var` once. If you shadow the global variable by a local declaration, the local variable will be used.

For example, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c) for information on how the shadowing works.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main()
{  
    int var=1;
    cout<<var;
    fun();
}
```

At the moment you're just modifying the global rather than creating a new one scoped in `main()`.

Then your output will be

```
10
```

Answer (score 2):

After assigning `1` to `var`, you are printing 2 times the same variable - note that you aren't creating 2 diffrent variables but you're changing the value of your variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I unerstand your post correctly, but he is not declaring another var, just changing the value of the global variable.  In the specific case above, he won't see 11 because of the specific values used.

Comment: Yes, I haven't see that there wasn't int before var = 1

Answer (score -1):

Var=0
Then var=1
Print var two times
Output 11

Comment: I think this is rather a comment than an answer, you could add more information to make it an answer however.