# Mario problem set - why won't the hashes print?

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently trying to print a pyramid of hashes for the Mario problem set (less comfortable), and they won't print. Would someone be able to look at my code and pinpoint where I am going wrong? Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int height;
int hashes;
int space;

do 
{
    int height = get_int("height: ");
}
while (height < 0 || height > 5);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int hashes = i;
        for (hashes = (i + 1); hashes >= height; hashes++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Watch for the **scope** of variables! Can you see where you are using [shadow variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c)?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using CS50 Lab and `make` to compile. This program will *not* compile because of shadow variables (as mentioned in the comments by @Weather Vane), and other errors. Therefore, I assume the executable that's running (i.e. `./mario`) was the last good compile of an older version of the source that did not print results.

The `for` loop in this code is an infinite loop. If you correct the compile errors, you will see nothing but `#`.

Recommend you delete the "old" compiled version (`rm mario` in the terminal) and then modify the code so 1) it compiles and 2) does not create an infinite loop.

Remember, you *declare* a variable including the type, as here: `int height;`. But when you *use* the variable (as here `int height = get_int("height: ");`) you do not use the type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code, hope it helps**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
 int main(void){


int height ;
do
{printf("height: ");
    height = get_int();
}
while(height<0 || height>23);

for(int i=1;i<height+1;i++)
{

    for(int j=0;j<height-i;j++)
    {
        printf("%s"," ");
    }
    for(int l=0;l<1;l++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
{
    printf("#");


}

printf("\n");


}
}
```