# How do you disambiguate a local static variable and a global variable that have the same name

Tags: c, gcc

below is my code:

```
//main.c

int x = 9;

int f()
{
    static int x = 0;
    x += 1;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", f());
   return 0;
}
```

my questions are:

Q1-inside `f()`, there is a local static varaible `x` defined, and there is gloabal variable also called `x`, the program does compile, but isn't it a conflict to the compiler and linker?

Q2-when I run it, the output is 1, which means that the `x` in `x += 1;` is the local static varaible `x`, not the gloabal variable `x`.But I could have mean "increment the global variable x", how can I do it?

Comment: There are two often-recommended options: A) avoid global variables B) name your variables meaningfully

Comment: Add `-Wshadow` to your compile string for gcc/clang or use `/W3` with VS. You are showing the global `x` in `f()`. E.g. `"warning: declaration of ‘x’ shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]"`

Comment: Read also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c

Comment: Yeah..umm..just rename one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1-inside f(), there is a local static varaible x defined, and there is gloabal variable also called x, isn't it a conflict to the compiler and linker?

No, the function always treats the local variable name first. The local name `x` in function `f` shadows the global name `x`.

> Q2-when I run it, the output is 1, which means that the x in x += 1; is the local static varaible x, not the gloabal variable x.But I could have mean "increment the global variable x", how can I do it?

It's the same as your first question. You call `f()` which uses the local variable name `x`, which shadows the global name `x`. If you want the global `x`, you need to use it directly, not via function `f`.

Comment: so it is not possible to call gloabl variable x via function `f`?

Answer (score 4):

A program can have the same name for local and global variables but the **value of a local variable inside a function will take preference**. There is no provision in C language to explicitly modify global variable with the same name as local inside local scope. In C++ though for accessing the global variable with same name, you'll have to use the scope resolution operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Global variable declaration:
int g = 20;
int f()
{
   int g = 0;
   ::g += 5;
   return g;
}

int main () {
   // Local variable declaration:
   int g = 10;

   cout << f();   // Local
   cout << ::g; // Global
   return 0;
}
```

Produces
0
25

Edit -
There is indeed a way to explicitly change the global scope variable inside local scope having same variable name ( only if global variable is not declared static )

```
int x = 9;

int f()
{
    static int x = 0;
    
    {
       extern int x;
       x += 1;
    }
    
    return x;
}

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", f());
   return 0;
}
```

Produces 0

Comment: Oh, this is interesting, is the `extern` declaration to access global scope a standard thing? Any resources you could point to?

Comment: http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~freedman/241/241notes/241var2.htm

Comment: That's just basics of how `extern` works, not really the behaviour you mention here.

Answer (score 1):

Once conceptually, program control reaches the local declaration of `x` in `f`, the global `x` is *shadowed*. No syntax exists in C for accessing the global `x`.

Other than renaming one of the variables,

```
int f()
{
    int* y = &x; // still refers to the global x
    static int x = 0;
    x += 1;
    *y += 1; // increments the global x via the pointer
    return x;
}
```

is an option, although not particularly sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. The language was intentionally designed this way so that we don't have to worry about what identifiers that reside in the global namespace - there can be quite a lot of them in large projects.

Internally the compiler doesn't use variable names at all, but sometimes their names must preserved for the purpose of generating debugger files (like ELF etc). In such situations, the compiler uses something called "name mangling" to keep the two variables separate internally. For example if I disassemble your code with gcc x86 and no optimizations, it names the local one `x.0` internally, where the `.0` thing is a compiler-specific addition, not to be confused with valid C syntax.

Q2. From inside the function `f` where the local `x` is visible, you can't. Unless you explicitly pass along a pointer to the other variable through a parameter etc. Again, we wouldn't want to change file scope variable values by accident.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1 -inside `f()`, there is a local static variable `x` defined, and there is global variable also called `x`, the program does compile, but isn't it a conflict to the compiler and linker?

No, it is not a conflict. What is going on here is the proce [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). The local `x` shadows the global `x`.

> Q2 - when I run it, the output is 1, which means that the `x` in `x += 1;` is the local static variable `x`, not the global variable `x`. But I could have mean "increment the global variable x", how can I do it?

Declare the global variable new with `extern` inside an inner scope and return from that scope:

```
int f (void)
{
    static int x = 0;
    {
        extern x;
        x += 1;
        return x;
    }   
}
```

Note that this won't work if the global `x` would be declared as `static` without adding code at the global space.