# Array gives different values in main() and in a function()

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to store a 1d array that stores random numbers into another 2d array.

So as you can see, I am trying to store the passed random array `a1` from the `main()` function to the `test()` function. And then I am adding it into `p[][]`. But I don't know why when I am trying to output the array `p[][]` in the main function, it is giving different values from what I have passed to it!

I would highly appreciate your help. As I need to reuse the stored data in `p[][]` in order to finish my task.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int p[9][9];

void test(int arr[], int rowCount){
    
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
        p[rowCount][j]=arr[j];
        cout << p[rowCount][j] << " ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
    
}

int main()
{
    int a1[9];
    int p[9][9];
    
    int rowCount=0;
    
    int no = 9;
    while(no!=0){
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            a1[i] = rand()%100;
        }
        test(a1, rowCount++);
        no--;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
            cout<<p[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
P[][] array in test()
41 67 34 0 69 24 78 58 62
64 5 45 81 27 61 91 95 42
27 36 91 4 2 53 92 82 21
16 18 95 47 26 71 38 69 12
67 99 35 94 3 11 22 33 73
64 41 11 53 68 47 44 62 57
37 59 23 41 29 78 16 35 90
42 88 6 40 42 64 48 46 5
90 29 70 50 6 1 93 48 29


P[][] array in main()
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
```

Comment: You have two different `p`'s, so to speak.

Comment: The function named `test` writes its values into the global variable `p`, while `main` displays contents from a local variable `p`. Why should those two things have anything to do with each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access a shadowed global variable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c)

Comment: Thank you dears. The problem was in `int p[9][9];` in main().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different `p` arrays: One in main and one global. The print loop in main is accessing the local `p` in main while `test` accesses the global one. That means only the global `p` gets filled with data and main is stuck with a different array that wasn't filled with data.

Remove the `int p[9][9];` in main. That line creates a second array that *shadows* the first (global) one.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that :D. Yes, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!